# Specify a custom "Movie rec. size" on Canon Rebel

Tags: canon, framerate

Can you specify a custom "Movie rec. size" on Canon Rebel?

I have an SL1, and I'm trying to record at 1280x720 with 30fps.  When I go the "Menu" screen I see that you can set "Movie rec. size." It gives me four preset options. At 1080p, it records at 30fps and at 720p it records at 60fps, without an apparent ability to set them independently.

I do see however that changing the Video system to PAL takes it down to 50fps, but I'd like to stick with the NTSC standard of 30fps.

Is this possible? --to set a custom "movie rec size" on my Canon SL1 to 1280x720 with a fps of 30?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no. The presets you get are what you are stuck with.

If you can do 1920x1080 at 30fps, it's easy enough to use a video editor or converter to go down to 1280x720 with minimal loss.

I frequently would record at 1080p on a Canon DSLR, and then finish and render at 720p (with the same framerate).

Comment: As a matter of fact, shooting at 1080p and scaling to 720p will make the image sharper, as well as saving some shots that were slightly slightly out of focus.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the "wheel" located between the ISO button and the shutter release. There is an icon on the screen that looks like a rising sun.